# Why are my ENVE SES wheels rubbing on frame when Zipp 303 didn't? Same tyres

Tags: tire, wheels

The 25mm tires are rubbing and they didn't when I had Zipp 303 on Cannondale 2017 EVO.

Seems like every time I put any pressure or even turn, tyres rub the frame. I'm only 140lbs (63 kg) and this is my 3rd Cannondale EVO but never have had any issues until adding ENVE wheels.

I added the Enve last year. They didn't rub during the Cache Gran Fondo only started after I got home (Colorado).  They've never really rubbed, just started after Gran Fondo trip.  I'm using the same Continental Gator Skin tyres as I had on the earlier on Zipp 303 wheels.

Comment: What rim width are the ENVE rims? what width were the previous rims? Did you have 25mm tyres before?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  It might help if you include a picture of where it is rubbing.  Is the rear or the front?  It appears that ENVE wheelsets come standard with some models of the EVO, so maybe it's the tire size that's a problem?

Comment: This site is intended to be oriented around objective questions and answers, check out the [Tour] to see how it works. Do you have a specific question about the tire rub?

Comment: Check your skewers for deformation.  Check for frame for damage and cracks.  While still, can you push the wheel rim sideways with hand pressure till it touches the frame?

Comment: Also check for a loose or broken spoke, this will compromise the wheel integrity

Comment: Slightly off topic, but if you can afford zipp/enve wheels, why on earth are you using gatorskins?

Comment: Your wheels might need re-tensioning. Not unusual for a new set of wheels.

Comment: *just started after Gran Fondo trip*  Oh?  Any long descents on the Gran Fondo?  Did you drag your brakes constantly down any descent to prevent your speed from building up?  If so, you may have deformed your wheel(s) by overheating them.

Answer (score 3):

Many rear wheels with high-profile rims lack lateral stiffness. The beefy rim itself may be stiff, but there may be too few, too thin spokes, possibly at too small angles. As a result, when you ride out of saddle the rim and tire may be moving sideways enough to rub the frame or brake pads.

Here's a very good article if you're interested in this in detail: [Debunking Wheel Stiffness](https://www.slowtwitch.com/Tech/Debunking_Wheel_Stiffness_3449.html)

Also, you're not alone with this problem with Enve SES wheels: [ENVE SES 4.5 with ENVE hub => brake rub](https://weightweenies.starbike.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=147610)